# play-scala and zenContact app

Tags: scala, playframework

After downloaded the play-scala project (and installed Play-Scala), I tried to start the [zenContact](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/tree/master/samples-and-tests/zencontact) demo application. IN the console, everything looks OK.

But when I refresh my browser, I have this message : Application.index action not found.

Does anyone of you have already see this message ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. The issue was that the scala play plugin was not installed correctly. Try this.

```
play install scala
play dependencies --sync
play run
```

Comment: But when I executed once again play install, I  have got this error (translated from french) : The process can not access to this file, because it is used by an other process jline.jar.
What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: In fact, after restarting my computetr, I did have the error message. But I always have the initial problem !